# Setting dynamic library path and license info in Xcode for C++ code

Tags: c++, xcode, dyld

I am a new Xcode user (version 3.2.2; Mac 10.6.7).

I have written C++ code that needs to be used in combination with commercial code.  I can run the code in a terminal window, but not in Xcode (error described below).  The commercial code uses a license and it also has dynamic libraries.  My problem is probably related to these issues.  The commercial code writers are not familiar with Xcode.

When I run the code in Xcode, this is the error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: 
Referenced from: /Users/me/Desktop/executableName
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap
logout
```

To run the code successfully in a Terminal window (not Xcode), I first do:
1) export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
2) export LM_LICENSE_FILE=1234@lic-xxx.xxx.xx

In Xcode, I think that this should be set in:
Project menu --> Edit Active Executable --> Variables to be set in the environment as:

Name: LM_LICENSE_FILE; Value: 1234@lic-xxx.xxx.xx Name: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH; Value: /Applications/myCode/libraries/xxx

But when I do this, I get the error above.

One further piece of information is, my code is in
Code:
/Applications
. But my Xcode project is saved at
Code:
/Users/me/Desktop/executableName
. The error message DOES say "referenced from" the desktop. Could this indicate a problem? What?

Comment: Why was it down-voted? Is it a bad question? Is it unanswerable?

Comment: +1, good question just misplaced